# Bacteria Producing Ultraviolet Light

Tags: biology, creature-design

I have species of bacteria that produce ultraviolet light serving as the basis for an underground ecosystem. What are possible food sources for this bacteria that are growing on the cave ceiling, about a kilometer above the cavern floor?

Comment: Unless you tell us the mechanism via which these bacteria emit UV light (I suspect it's impossible), we cannot come with an answer.

Comment: That's *a lot* of light. You'd need at least 10 W / sq. meter to grow anything at all, and close to 50 W / sq. meter in order to approach natural vegetable growth rates. See [grow light](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grow_light) for the painfully detailed details. Remember that the bacteria are basically replacing the Sun, and the Sun is powered by nuclear fusion.

Comment: I don't understand why this is on hold. He asked for a viable food source for bacteria in a described ecosystem, what more do you need?

Comment: Just realized there are two radically different ways to understand this question: 1) "My ecosystem runs on **light** produced by bio-luminescent bacteria - what's a reasonable food source for that bacteria?" or 2) "My ecosystem's food-chain starts with a bacteria (it is **eaten** by others etc.), it happens to be bio-luminescent - what's a reasonable food source for that bacteria?". The first interpretation is problematic for a science based answer, since the amount of energy required exceeds anything familiar (to my limited understanding, at least). However the second is quite reasonable IMO.

Comment: Unfortunately I meant the first version of the question, I guess I should have asked about making the actual biological process feasible first

Comment: @Thalassan Probably a good idea.